# Swift - how to store a struct instance in a class propriety

Tags: swift, class, struct, initialization, instance

I am **very** new to Swift so I apologize upfront if this is a "dumb" question. I am just working on a playgrounds script for generating random items, in this case, weapons. When I run my code I get this error: **error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).** What I was trying to do is hold an instance of a structure(which is handle) in my class normalBladeType in variable weaponHandle. I've tried researching about this topic but I've yet to find an answer. Any suggestions would be great. For all I know I may be going about this all wrong.

Thanks,

my code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa



let handleWoods = ["White Ash", "Oak", "White Oak", "Elm", "Maple","Walnut", "Cherry", "Rosewood", "Ash", "Hickory", "Birch", "Hemlock", "Cedar", "Pine"]
let handleGrips = ["Leather", "Buckskin", "Sharkskin", "Goat Skin", "Deerskin", "Elk Skin", "Rayskin", "Snakeskin", "Silk Cord", "Cotton Cord"]
let gripQualities = ["Simple", "Interwoven", "Ornate", "Smooth", "Thin", "Thick", "Ruff", "Worn"]

func returnRandomItem( _ list: [Any])-> Any {
    return list[Int(UInt32(list.count))]
}




struct handle {
    var name: String
    var value, grip: Int
    var weight: Double
    var withGrip: Bool

    init(withGrip: Bool) {
        self.weight = 0.25
        self.withGrip = withGrip
        let handleNameWithWood = "\(returnRandomItem(handleWoods)) Handle"
        if self.withGrip {
            let randGrip = "\(returnRandomItem(gripQualities)) \(returnRandomItem(handleGrips)) Grip)"
            self.name = "\(randGrip) (\(handleNameWithWood))"
            self.grip = 75
            self.value = 2
        } else {
            self.name = handleNameWithWood
            self.grip = 50
            self.value = 1
        }
    }

    func description() {
        print("Handle Description \(self.name)")
        }

}


class weapon {
    var TypeOfWeapon: String
    var weaponHandle: handle

    init(weaponType: String, doesHaveGrip: Bool) {
        self.TypeOfWeapon = weaponType
        self.weaponHandle = handle(withGrip: doesHaveGrip)
    }
}

class normalBladeType: weapon {
    init() {
        super.init(weaponType: "normalBladeType", doesHaveGrip: false)
    }

    func description() {
        print("TypeOfWeapon: \(self.TypeOfWeapon)")
        print("TypeDescription: normal hilt (guard - handle - pommel) + straight blade")
    }
}


var foo = normalBladeType()
foo.description()
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the source code for `returnRandomItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `returnRandomItem` function is wrong. You should change it to

```
func returnRandomItem( _ list: [Any])-> Any {
    let index: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count))
    return list[Int(index)]
}
```

It is working fine for me with this code.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling that there may have been a problem elsewhere. I was taking a shot in the dark with the struct in a class stuff(I tried looking at the documentation, etc, spent a day looking for the wrong problem it turns out).